# How to add delay between filling FixedThreadPool

Tags: java, multithreading, fixed, pool, setting

How can I add delay when empty queue is filling with next thread?
Ex:

```
int numberOfThreads = 55;

private static ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);

int counter=0;
for(TblHomePageUrl tblHomePageUrl : mainTable)
{
    legalInstituteIDList.add(tblHomePageUrl.getIntLegalInstitutionID());

    WPCrawlerThread wpThread = new WPCrawlerThread(tblHomePageUrl, maxDepth, politenessDelay);
    executor.execute(wpThread);
    threadList.add(wpThread);

    if(counter<=numThreads){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {}
    }
    counter++;                      
}
```

I'm sending post request to google when start each Thread.
If 2 or 3 thread run same time I am blocking from Google. If i can add a small delay between filling threads. I'll stay away from blocking. I'm using java. I need to setting to executor.

Comment: You need to provide more information to get a helpful answer. What language do you use? What are you trying to achieve? What is the actual problem? Can you share some code?

Comment: You are right thanks for help. This is my first question sory for my fault. I edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try to use [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) instead of `ExecutorService`. The documentation about `ScheduledExecutorService` says:

> An ExecutorService that can schedule commands to run after a given
>   delay, or to execute periodically.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I solved the problem I think. I used synchronized method for google search. I dint try on server, But it must be work.